# Use single in-memory Sqlite connection shared among all unit test modules?

Tags: python, sqlite, pytest

I am running numerous unit tests using `pytest` and have several types of database interactions occurring in each unit test module.

My ideal goal is to setup a single `sqlite:///:memory:` environment with tables pre-created, data inserted, etc only once (instead of doing this once for each module) that can be shared among my entire test suite, but I am just not sure how to do this properly.

Here is a sample of the `tests` package.

```
$ tree tests/
tests
├── __init__.py
├── conftest.py
├── test_thing1.py
├── test_thing2.py
└── test_thing3.py
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037924/populating-sqlite-in-memory-for-unit-testing) related question but I would prefer to use sqlite in-memory for the obvious performance gains.

My `conftest.py` current contains:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def test_db():
    """Returns an object for which a SqlAlchemy engine and session object can be obtained"""
    yield DatabaseThing(**db_conf)
```

Comment: Use a session-scoped fixture for the db setup; this way, the db will be initialised once and shared between the tests in the test suite.

Comment: Thanks.  But can I have a fixture that references a another fixture?  I currently have a fixture within `conftest.py` that yields an object from which a `SqlAlchemy` `engine` and `session` are tested from.  I will update the question about to make this more clear.

Comment: You can reference other fixtures via fixture arguments, e.g. `test_db` variable in `def myfixture(test_db): ...` will have the return value of `test_db` fixture.

Comment: Is it worth the bother?  How much faster are your tests against an in-memory database than an on-disk one?  Unless your test data are quite large, the disk I/O will likely be charged against the file buffer.

Comment: I am giving that a try now but not sure how to globally setup an environment across all the modules.  I tried putting a `setup()` function in my `conftest.py` that contains the table creation, row insertion, etc but that doesnt appear to be working as hoped.